# Readable user agent api or php array list?

Tags: php, user-agent

I am getting user agent but i want show user agent to people's like this;

User Agent ;

```
 Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SAMSUNG SM-G950F Build/NRD90M)
 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/5.2
 Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

İ want show this like ;

```
Samsung Galaxy S8, Samsung Browser , Android 7.0
```

I dont care mozilla , build , webkit or versions . I want just device name , browser name and operating system + version.
Is there an ArrayList or device detector API to do this?

Comment: [mobiledetect](http://mobiledetect.net/) simple composer library you can include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try [ThaDafinser/UserAgentParser](https://github.com/ThaDafinser/UserAgentParser) package. check their demo [here](http://useragent.mkf.solutions/?userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Linux%3B%20Android%204.3%3B%20SCH-R970C%20Build%2FJSS15J%29%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20%28KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko%29%20Chrome%2F34.0.1847.114%20Mobile%20Safari%2F537.3) (example with a Samsung Galaxy S4) to see which provider suits you best.